# Using a SSL client certificate with IXMLHTTPRequest3

Tags: c++, windows, http, ssl-certificate, client-certificates

I am using [IXMLHTTPRequest3](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn376398(v=vs.85).aspx) from C++ code to issue a request to a service. This request needs to be accompanied by a client certificate (which is just about the only thing that IXHR3 adds over IXHR2).

The certificate's thumbprint is 8D1CC03002D7872230516B5C5BA1090084D68ED0, and I have verified that it is installed on the computer:

```
PS> dir cert:\*\*\* | ? { $_.Thumbprint -eq "8D1CC03002D7872230516B5C5BA1090084D68ED0" }

    Directory: Microsoft.PowerShell.Security\Certificate::LocalMachine\My

Thumbprint                                Subject
----------                                -------
8D1CC03002D7872230516B5C5BA1090084D68ED0  DC=..., O=..., OU=...
```

However, when I try to pass that thumbprint to `IXHR3->SetClientCertificate`, I get back 0x80092004, `CRYPT_E_NOT_FOUND`.

I converted the hash from a hex string to a 20-byte array (through automation to avoid transposition mistakes on my end) and my invocation looks like this:

```
uint8_t thumbprint[20] = { 0x8d, 0x1c, 0xc0, 0x30, ... };
hr = request->SetClientCertificate(ARRAYSIZE(thumbprint), thumbprint, nullptr);
```

The question, clearly, is: why can't IXHR3 find my client certificate?

Comment: Do you have the same problem if you use [`CryptUIDlgSelectCertificateFromStore()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380288.aspx) to choose the certificate? See [this example](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/blob/master/Samples/XmlHttpRequest3GetRequest/cpp/XMLHttpRequest3Get.cpp), which uses a `SelectCert()` method from [this implementation](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/blob/master/Samples/XmlHttpRequest3GetRequest/cpp/XMLHttpRequest3Callback.cpp).

Comment: @RemyLebeau, I should first note that this runs on Azure. The real process is launched in a non-interactive session, so there's no way for me to see what actually happens there. However, when I manually run the program through RDP, my certificate shows up, and when I select it, it gives the thumbprint that I expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IXHR3 only looks for certificates in `CERT_STORE_PROV_SYSTEM` -> `CERT_SYSTEM_STORE_CURRENT_USER`, and mine was in `CERT_SYSTEM_STORE_LOCAL_MACHINE` instead.